# active link in menu bar not working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am unable to put " a:hover " on my home button in menu bar. even unable to remove the text-decoration. 
while i was trying my hands on media queries , just got puzzled.

****stack overflow settings is not allowing me to post question unless i add more details*****

```css
body {
 background-image: url("blue-bokeh.jpeg");
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.wrap {
 height: auto;
 width: 90%;
 margin: auto;
}

header {
 background: #333;
 color: white;
 height: auto;
 width:100%;
 float: left;
}

header nav {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}

header nav ul {
 list-style: none;
 height: auto;
 width: auto; /* what happens if i change the value to 100% */
 float: right;
 margin-right:30px;
}

header nav ul li {
 display: inline;
 padding: 15px 30px;
 float: left;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

header nav ul li a.active {
    text-decoration: none;
}

header nav ul li:hover {
 background-color: #111;
}

header nav ul li a.active:active {
    background-color: #4caf50;
}

.mainbody {
 /*background: tomato;*/  /* get the code checked , if its repeated in .top class */
 float: left;
 margin-top: 20px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 /*padding: 20px 20px;*/
 height: auto;
 width: 60%;
 margin-right: 2%;
}

.top {
 background: tomato;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 float: left;
 border-radius: 10px;
 padding: 20px 20px;
}

.top h3 {
 color: darkslategray

}

.bottom {
 background: tomato;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
 float: left;
 border-radius: 10px;
 padding: 20px 20px;
}

.bottom h3 {
 color: darkslategray

}

.sidebar {
 float: left;
 height: auto;
 width: 38%;
 margin-top: 20px;

}

.topside {
 background: orangered;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 padding: 20px 20px;
}

.middleside {
 background: orangered;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 padding: 20px 20px;
}

.bottomside {
 background: orangered;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 border-radius: 10px;
 padding: 20px 20px;
}

footer {
 background: darkslategray;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

footer p {
 padding-left: 50px;
}


/* ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ------------------------------------------------------MEDIA QUERY STARTS HERE---------------------------------------------------------------*/

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    body {
     background-image: url("blue-bokeh.jpeg");
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
    }
    
    .wrap {
     height: auto;
     width: 90%;
     margin: auto;
    }
    
    header {
     background: #444;
     color: white;
     height: auto;
     width:100%;
    }
    
    header nav {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
    }
    
    header nav ul {
     list-style: none;
     height: auto;
     width: 100%; /* what happens if i change the value to 100% */
     margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
       
    }
    
    header nav ul li {
     display: block;
     padding: 15px 30px;
        float: none;
    }
    
    header nav ul li:hover {
     background-color: #111;
    }
    
    header nav ul li a.active:active {
        background-color: #4caf50; 
    }
    
    .mainbody {
     /*background: tomato;*/  /* get the code checked , if its repeated in .top class */
     margin-top: 20px;
     border-radius: 10px;
     /*padding: 20px 20px;*/
     height: auto;
     width: 100%;
    }
    
    .top {
     background: tomato;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;
     padding: 20px 20px;
    }
    
    .top h3 {
     color: darkslategray
    
    }
    
    .bottom {
     background: tomato;
     border-radius: 10px;
     padding: 20px 20px;
    }
    
    .bottom h3 {
     color: darkslategray
    
    }
    
    .sidebar {
     height: auto;
     width: 100%;
    
    }
    
    .topside {
     background: orangered;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;
     padding: 20px 20px;
    }
    
    .middleside {
     background: orangered;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;
     padding: 20px 20px;
    }
    
    .bottomside {
     background: orangered;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     border-radius: 10px;
     padding: 20px 20px;
    }
    
    footer {
     background: darkslategray;
     float: left;
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     border-radius: 10px;
    }
    
    footer p {
     padding-left: 50px;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link href="restheme.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrap">
  <header>
   <nav>
    <ul>
     <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
     <li>Portfolio</li>
     <li>Blog</li>
     <li>Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
   </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="mainbody">
   <article class="top">
    <h3>First Post</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
   </article>

   <article class="bottom">
    <h3>Second Post</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>
   </article>
  </div> 
  <div class="sidebar">
   <aside class="topside">
    <h3>Top Sidebar</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
   </aside>

   <aside class="middleside">
    <h3>Middle Sidebar</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
   </aside>

   <aside class="bottomside">
    <h3>Bottom Sidebar</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
   </aside>
  </div>

  <footer>
   <p>Copyright &copy; 2016 Faltoo Webdesigns</p> 
  </footer>

 </div>
</body> 
 

</html>
```

Comment: Can you be more precise? What should happen? I don't see a text-decoration.

Comment: i want it to be like this (see that home button is active and has green color)

http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_responsive

Comment: But there you already have the CSS code...

Comment: still i could not understand the fault in my code  , thats why

Comment: You don't set the color to white so the user-agent color for the anchor is taken (blue).

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to achive something like this?

https://jsfiddle.net/j7j54Lta/1/

I did some improvements and changed the structure. The li gets the .active-class and not the anchor. If the anchor in the active li is hovered it changes the color (or whatever you want to achive):

```
header nav ul li.active a:hover{
  color: red;
  /* or whatever*/
}
```

Moreover there is no text-decoration:

```
header nav ul li.active a {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: yes ! but the "home" text is highlighted, i want the text-decoration set to none ; thanks

Comment: you can see how the text " home" is in blue color , indicating it to be a link

Comment: Well just add `header nav ul li a{  color: white; }` and remove the `header nav ul li.active a:hover{ color: red; }` - https://jsfiddle.net/j7j54Lta/2/